How to ignore large file uploads in git? For example dependencies?
Good afternoon everyone.
An error occurs when uploading a repository to Git.
This is error "File Pods/MyPath/YandexMapsMobile.xcframework/ios-x86_64_arm64-simulator/YandexMapsMobile.framework/YandexMapsMobile is 409.37 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB  GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com."
Tell me how to ignore file uploads in Git?
I found a solution for another project, but did not save the example. I can’t google it anyway.
Adding to the gitignore file didn't help.

You could use GitLFS as package to handle large files.
https://git-lfs.com/

I found the following solution:
1 Created a repository on github.
2 Connected the project to github.
3 Created a file on the gitignore site - gitignore.io.  I entered a line that should be ignored.  
4 Created a file .gitignore in the project folder via the terminal - touch .gitignore.
5 Copied the data received from the site to .gitignor.
6 Created a comment and pushed the project to git.
This video shows how to make gitignore
